# A difficult web-scrape - Multiple values of interest in the same cell

Tags: python, pandas

I am having some issues with web-scraping the wiki polls for the Spanish Political Parties (Link below). The issue is that the cells contain both the % score in the poll (the top number), but also the number of seats this equates to in Spanish Parliament. I have been using a basic Pandas web-scrape (read_html) for my other polling web-scrapes and they work fine. I am not sure if Pandas is even capable to read the numbers separately, so any guidance would be great.

For reference, when you do pd.read_html, this table is table 1, so df[0].

Link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_next_Spanish_general_election

[image]

---

Current Code

```
def _import():

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_next_Spanish_general_election'

all_tables = pd.read_html(url, header=1)
df = all_tables[0]

df.drop(df.tail(3).index,inplace=True)
df.drop(['Turnout','Lead'],axis=1,inplace=True)

return df

df = _import()

columns = ['Polling firm/Commissioner','Fieldwork date','Sample 
            size','PSOE','PP','VOX','Unidas Podemos','CS',
            'ERC–Sobiranistes','Más País','JxCat','PNV','EH Bildu','CUP','CC- 
             NCa','BNG','Navarra Suma','PRC']

df.columns = columns

#df.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
 names = ['PSOE','PP','VOX','Unidas Podemos','CS', 
          'ERC–Sobiranistes','Más País','JxCat','PNV',
           'EH Bildu','CUP','CC-NCa','BNG','Navarra Suma','PRC']

for column in names: 
    df[[column + ' Percent', column + ' Number of Seats']] =  df[column].str.extract('(\d+\.\d)(.*)')

df.drop(columns=[column], inplace=True)

df.head()
```

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT ERROR

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-a02976f2ddae> in <module>
     22 for column in names:
     23     df[[column + ' Percent', column + ' Number of Seats']] = 
df[column].str.extract('(\d+\.\d)(.*)')
---> 24     df[column + ' Number of Seats'] = df[column + ' Number of 
Seats'].apply(average)
     25     df.drop(columns=[column], inplace=True)
     26 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in 
apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3846             else:
   3847                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3848                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, 
convert=convert_dtype)
   3849 
   3850         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-20-6660ac0c6321> in average(text)
      1 def average(text):
----> 2     if '/' in text:
      3         a, b = text.split('/')
      4         text = str( (int(a) + int(b)) // 2 )  # average integer value
      5     return text

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

---

Comment: I see it gives string like `26.6107` and you can simply slice it `"26.6107"[:4]` gives `'26.6'`

Comment: in question you should keep original code without my changes and below old code add new code with header `EDIT:`. Now your code with changes doesn't fit to my answer - it seems my answer is useless for your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `read_html` has options to read it as separated values - you would have to check it in documentation.

But it gives both values `26.6`,`107` as string like `26.6107` and you can simply slice it

```
df[0]['PSOE percent'] = df[0]['Unnamed: 4'].str[:4]   # 26.6
df[0]['PSOE number']  = df[0]['Unnamed: 4'].str[4:]   # 107
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_next_Spanish_general_election'

all_tables = pd.read_html(url, header=1)

df = all_tables[0]

for column in df.columns: 
    if column.startswith('Unnamed:'):
        df[column+' percent'] = df[column].str[:4]
        df[column+' number']  = df[column].str[4:]
        df.drop(columns=[column], inplace=True)

print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You changed code in question and now you should use

```
names = ['PSOE','PP','VOX','Unidas Podemos','CS', 
         'ERC–Sobiranistes','Más País','JxCat','PNV',
         'EH Bildu','CUP','CC-NCa','BNG','Navarra Suma','PRC']

for column in names: 
     df[column+' percent'] = df[column].str[:4]
     df[column+' number']  = df[column].str[4:]
     df.drop(columns=[column], inplace=True)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version which search dot in string to find place where it has to split it.

I needs to use `apply` to execute code on every cell and return pairs `(percent, number)`. Later it needs `apply(np.Series)` to convert single column with pairs `(percent, number)` into two columns with separated `percent` and `number`. Or it has to use `.str[0]`, `.str[1]` to get values

```
names = ['PSOE','PP','VOX','Unidas Podemos','CS', 
         'ERC–Sobiranistes','Más País','JxCat','PNV',
         'EH Bildu','CUP','CC-NCa','BNG','Navarra Suma','PRC']

import numpy as np

def split_text(text):
    dot = text.find('.')
    if dot > -1:
        percent = text[:dot+2]
        number = text[dot+2:] 
    else:
        percent = np.NaN
        number = np.NaN
    return (percent, number)
    
for column in names: 
    result = df[column].apply(split_text)

    #df[ [column+' percent', column+' number'] ] = result.apply(pd.Series)

    df[column+' percent'] = result.str[0]
    df[column+' number'] = result.str[1]

    df.drop(columns=[column], inplace=True)
    
print(df[ ['PRC percent', 'PRC number'] ])
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can do it also with `regex`

```
for column in names: 
    df[ [column+' percent', column+' number'] ] = df[column].str.extract("(\d+\.\d)(.*)")
    
    df.drop(columns=[column], inplace=True)
```

---

**EDIT:**

To convert `121/123` to average value you can use `.apply(my_function)` and this function can use normal `split('/')`, convert values to `int`, calcuate average, and convert back to text.

**EDIT:**
It seems sometimes it can get `float` instead of `string` so it needs to check `isinstance(text, str)`.

I also convert all values to `float` but I have to skip for empty strings and `?`. I found also value with `11.8[b]` and I skip `[.]` in regex
23/25

```
def average(text):
    #print(text)
    if  isinstance(text, str) and ('/' in text):
        a, b = text.split('/')
        text = (int(a) + int(b)) // 2
        
    if text and (text != '?'):
        return float(text)
    else:        
        return text
    
for column in names: 
    df[[column + ' Percent', column + ' Number of Seats']] = df[column].str.extract('(\d+\.\d)(?:\[.\])?(.*)')
    
    df[column + ' Number of Seats'] = df[column + ' Number of Seats'].apply(average)

df.drop(columns=[column], inplace=True)

print(df.head())
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the fix works great. An issue this throws up is that while this works for the first 3 columns, the next column has a mix of 2 and 3 digit percentages, so do you have any suggestions to over come this?

Comment: I have updated my code in the original bit to reflect your code

Comment: So now you have to use `for name in ['PSOE','PP','VOX','Unidas Podemos','CS',
       'ERC–Sobiranistes','Más País','JxCat','PNV','EH Bildu','CUP','CC-NCa','BNG','Navarra Suma','PRC',]` instead of `for column in df.columns:  if column.startswith('Unnamed:'):`

Comment: you can find dot in text and use this position to split it

Comment: I added example which search dot to split it. Eventually you could use `regex` for this.

Comment: The code works great thank you so much. The final problem that I have been working on for this is some columns now have the values "121/123" for example. Do you know how I could use the same extract method to find the point of "/", and the just take and average of the two numbers?

Comment: I have updated the OP with the current code

Comment: first I will repeate: don't change original question but add new information at the end of the question - ie with `EDIT:` or `UPDATE:`. Now my answer doesn't fit to your question. And it seem useless. And other people will don't know why I even wrote all this code.

Comment: what do you want to do with this value - split `123` and `123 to separated colums or get only first value ? For char `/` may need `\/`  because `/` has special meaning in `regex`. i.e `(.*)\/(.*)` to split `123/456` into `123` and `456`, or `(.*)\/` to get only `123`.

Comment: Sorry about cancelling the original code out. I would need to split 121 and 123 (if the cell said 121/123), and then take the average of that. I think the best way to produce the output would be to create a new column with the output, then delete the old column? What do you think?

Comment: using `extract('(\d+\.\d)([^/]*)/?(.*)')` you can split original value into three columns - `[^/]*`  gets all chars except `/`, next `/?` gets `/` if exists, next `.*` gets rest. But to calculate average you have to convert columns to integers because values are still as strings. ie `df[column+' number'] = df[column+' number'].astype(int)`. But in third column you will have empty places when there was value without `/` and I don't know if average will works. OR you will have to select only rows with value in third column and then calculate average. I'm working on example code.

Comment: I added example which use `.apply(function)` to run own function on column `Number of Seats` - and this function uses normal `split('/')` to split text and calculate average value. And it doesn't need new column.

Comment: Thanks for all the help furas, i see how it works but I get an error when I run it. ERROR: argument of type 'float' is not iterable. Where do you think I am going wrong on this?

Comment: where do you get `float` ? I use `int()` and later convert back to `str()` to have the same type as cells which didn't have `/`. Error should show you in which line you have error and you could use `print(...)`, `print(type(...))` what you have in variables - maybe this way you will see which value can makes problem.

Comment: It comes in the line, "if '/' in text:", so somewhere in that loop?

Comment: don't add to my answer. Put it in your question or create new question on new page and you will have more space for code, error message and descriptiosn. And new people will see it.

Comment: Thanks, I have added it to my original question

Comment: error may suggest that you have values converted from string to float and now it try to do `if '/' in float_value` - but I don't see code which would convert it. But still you can check it you have string or not - `if isinstance(text, str) and ("/" in text):`

Comment: I added `isinstance(text, str)` to last code but I didn't test it.

Comment: I put changed code at the end of answer. I tested it and found places with empty strings, `?` - so I keep it as text - and few places like with `11.2[b]` so I skip `[.]` in regex.

Comment: Amazing thank you it works great! Really appreciate your help on this

Comment: If you have any learning resources that you recommend then please do let me know